# Smallest $n$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

A well-known result, Cayley's theorem, says that any group is isomorphic to $S_n$ for some $n$. Given a (finite) group $G$, is there a standard name for the smallest such $n$?

This seems like a very basic concept which has surely been studied and named, but my searches have found nothing so far.

Is it easy to calculate $n$? An obvious lower bound is the Kempner number [A002034](https://oeis.org/A002034)$(|G|)$.

---

Note: there is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289219/1778) but it doesn't address my issue.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you change the phrasing to "*isomorphic to* a subgroup of $S_n$".

Comment: Equivalently, you're asking for what the size of the smallest set that $G$ acts faithfully on. I've had this thought before, but don't remember coming to a conclusion--good question!

Comment: It appears this has been asked on overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48928/smallest-n-for-which-g-embeds-in-s-n

Comment: The term seems to be "minimal representation of a finite group", one link http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2373739?uid=3739832&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102519829547 [But it isn't free unless you're on JSTOR]

Comment: as far as all finite groups are concerned, Cayleys theorem gives best estimate for $n$, since $Q_8$ can not be embedded in $S_7$.

Comment: There is considerable literature on the subject, look up *minimal degree for a permutation representation:* http://goo.gl/TQAcZL

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191446/efficient-version-of-cayleys-theorem-in-group-theory is another duplicate